# Mean value of each element in multiple lists - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have two lists

```
a = [2,5,1,9]
b = [4,9,5,10]
```

How can I find the mean value of each element, so that the resultant list would be:

```
[3,7,3,9.5]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: sorry to be a stickler but your title implies mean value across multiple lists, whereas your question is actually about two lists. None of the answers mentioned would be efficient for, say, 2,234,983 lists

Comment: Fair point, think you can do better?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
>>> a = [2,5,1,9]
>>> b = [4,9,5,10]
>>> [(g + h) / 2 for g, h in zip(a, b)]
[3.0, 7.0, 3.0, 9.5]
```

Comment: In Python 2, the division is truncated (integer division), one way to work around that is to divide by a float (here: 2.0).

Answer (score 11):

Referring to your title of the question, you can achieve this simply with:

```
import numpy as np

multiple_lists = [[2,5,1,9], [4,9,5,10]]
arrays = [np.array(x) for x in multiple_lists]
[np.mean(k) for k in zip(*arrays)]
```

Above script will handle multiple lists not just two. If you want to compare the performance of two approaches try:

```
%%time
import random
import statistics

random.seed(33)
multiple_list = []
for seed in random.sample(range(100), 100):
    random.seed(seed)
    multiple_list.append(random.sample(range(100), 100))

result = [statistics.mean(k) for k in zip(*multiple_list)]
```

or alternatively:

```
%%time
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(33)
multiple_list = []
for seed in random.sample(range(100), 100):
    random.seed(seed)
    multiple_list.append(np.array(random.sample(range(100), 100)))

result = [np.mean(k) for k in zip(*multiple_list)]
```

To my experience numpy approach is much faster.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is the mean of two arrays (or vectors in math).

Since Python 3.4, there is a [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module which provides a `mean()` function:

> *statistics.mean(data)*
>
> Return the sample arithmetic mean of data, a sequence or iterator of real-valued numbers.

You can use it like this:

```
import statistics

a = [2, 5, 1, 9]
b = [4, 9, 5, 10]

result = [statistics.mean(k) for k in zip(a, b)]
# -> [3.0, 7.0, 3.0, 9.5]
```

*notice*: this solution can be use for more than two arrays, because `zip()` can have multiple parameters.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to using a list and for loop would be to use a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
# an array can perform element wise calculations unlike lists. 
a, b = np.array([2,5,1,9]), np.array([4,9,5,10]) 
mean = (a + b)/2; print(mean)
>>>[ 3.   7.   3.   9.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the two lists into a numpy array using vstack and then take the mean (using 'tolist' to get back from the numpy array):

```
import numpy as np
a = [2,5,1,9]
b = [4,9,5,10]
np.mean(np.vstack([a,b]), axis=0).tolist()
```

[3.0, 7.0, 3.0, 9.5]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for an element-wise mean value. setting axis=0 in np.mean is what you need.

```py
 >>> import numpy as np

 >>> a = [2,5,1,9]

 >>> b = [4,9,5,10]
```

Create a list containing all your lists

```py
>>> a_b = [a,b]

>>> a_b

[[2, 5, 1, 9], [4, 9, 5, 10]]
```

Use np.mean and set the axis to 0

```
>>> np.mean(a_b, axis=0)

array([3. , 7. , 3. , 9.5])
```